# orthogonal matrices and diagonal matrices multiplied

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

Proving $$(P^T P^T) \Lambda P P \equiv \Lambda$$ where $P$ is an orthogonal matrix, $\Lambda$ is diagonal matrix. All matrices have dimensions $n \times n$.

Since this is the last step of the proof shown in [$\chi^2$ for dependent Gaussian distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442472/sum-of-squares-of-dependent-gaussian-random-variables)
It is known that all diagonal elements of $\lambda_i \geq 0$

---

1. Multiplied orthogonal matrices give another orthogonal matrix

Proof:
$$
P \cdot P^T = I\\
Q := P \cdot P\\
P^{-1} = P^T\\
PP \cdot (PP)^T = PP \cdot P^T P^T = P I P^T = P \cdot P^T = I 
$$

So $Q$ is orthogonal as well.

---

2. How can I now prove that $Q \Lambda Q^T = \Lambda$?

For a full rank $\Lambda$ with equal diagonal elements and otherwise zero this can proven:
$Q \Lambda Q^T = Q \lambda \cdot I Q^T = \lambda Q \cdot Q^T = \lambda \cdot I = \Lambda$

**How can I prove this for the general case with differing diagonal elements?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is true. Counter example:
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$=
$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$