# Computing $E[\|X\|^4]$ for normal X

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, expected-value

The following seems to hold for $X$ distributed as 0-centered normal with covariance $\Sigma$, any suggestions how to show this analytically?

$$E[\|X\|^4] = \operatorname{tr}(\Sigma)^2+2\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma^2)$$

Comment: Someone already worked out an answer, but the distribution of $X^T X$ is also given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442472/sum-of-squares-of-dependent-gaussian-random-variables/442916)

Comment: The linked thread above does not concern itself with a general $\Sigma$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes it does

Comment: @StubbornAtom that is not a contradiction with the answer I referred to. I have posted an elegant answer based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lVert X\rVert^4=(X^TX)^2$, we have for $X\sim N(0,\Sigma)$,

\begin{align}
E\,[\lVert X\rVert^4]=E\,[(X^TX)^2]&=\operatorname{Var}[X^TX]+(E\,[X^TX])^2
\\&=2\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma^2)+(\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma))^2
\end{align}

The expectation of $X^T X$ for any vector $X$ is relatively straightforward, as shown [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48066/expected-value-of-quadratic-form).

The variance of $X^TX$ is a bit more work, but for normal $X$ it can be done by generalizing [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427332/variance-of-quadratic-form-for-multivariate-normal-distribution/) approach here.

For a reference regarding derivation of variance of quadratic forms in general, you can look up *[Linear Regression Analysis](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Linear+Regression+Analysis%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471415404)* by Seber and Lee (second edition, section 1.5).

Answer (score 1):

Write $\Sigma = P^T \Lambda P$, then:

$$X^TX = (\Sigma^{-1/2}X)^T P^T \Lambda P (\Sigma^{-1/2}X) = \sum_i \lambda_i U_i^2,$$
where $U = P \Sigma^{-1/2}X \sim N(0,I)$. So $X^TX$ is a weighted sum of independent $\chi^2_1$ variables. Therefore, the expected value of $X^TX$ is $\sum_i \lambda_i = \text{tr}(\Sigma)$ and the variance is $2 \sum_i \lambda^2 = 2\text{tr}(\Sigma^2)$.